# Jaxb. Customize field naming behavior(camelCase to underscore_case)

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-serialization

I want to serialize my fields with underscored names. For example: `userName` -> `user_name`.

I know that it can be done with the `@XmlElement(name = "user_name")` annotation, but it's not very handy for my case.

Is there any way to set up a default naming policy for JAXB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note:  I'm the EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) lead and a member of the JAXB (JSR-222) expert group.

MOXy has an `XMLNameTransformer` extension that enables you to override the default naming policy for elements, attributes, and types.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/overriding-jaxbs-name-mangling.html

If you generated your model from an XML schema you can use an external binding file to keep the underscores.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
  version="2.1">
  <jxb:globalBindings underscoreBinding="asCharInWord"/>
</jxb:bindings>
```