# JaxB adds undescore(_) when generating Enumerations from XSD

Tags: xml, enums, jaxb, xsd, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I use maven JaxB plugin to generate source from XSD.

The plugin details are as below,

```
<groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
<version>0.8.3</version>
```

Enumerations defined in XSD has two values,

```
<simpleType name="MyEnum">
    <restriction base="xsd:string">
        <enumeration value="SimpleText" />
        <enumeration value="ComplexText" />
    </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

The generated code adds underscore between work boundaries of the enum values. For eg:, "SimpleText" comes as SIMPLE_TEXT in enum.

Generated code,

```
@XmlType(name = "MyEnum")
@XmlEnum
public enum MyEnum {

   @XmlEnumValue("SimpleText")
   SIMPLE_TEXT("SimpleText"),
   @XmlEnumValue("ComplexText")
   COMPLEX_TEXT("ComplexText");
   private final String value;

   MyEnum(String v) {
      value = v;
   }

   public String value() {
      return value;
   }

   public static MyEnum fromValue(String v) {
      for (MyEnum c: MyEnum.values()) {
          if (c.value.equals(v)) {
              return c;
          }
      }
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(v);
   }
```

}

The problem occurs when an enumeration has same text separated with underscore at different places. For Eg;

```
<simpleType name="MyEnum">
    <restriction base="xsd:string">
        <enumeration value="My_Simple_Text" />
        <enumeration value="MySimple_Text" />
    </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

doesn't convert to an enum.
Is there any way to avoid JaxB adding underscore between words.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an external bindings file to customize the enum generation:

```
<jxb:bindings 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='MyEnum']/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value='My_Simple_Text']">
            <jxb:typesafeEnumMember name="FOO"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='MyEnum']/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value='MySimple_Text']">
            <jxb:typesafeEnumMember name="BAR"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

---

### UPDATE

Turns out the better approach is to use the following bindings file instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
  version="2.1">
  <jxb:globalBindings underscoreBinding="asCharInWord"/>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Comment: Do I have to specify every value by hand. Am looking for a flag if available to tell JaxB not to keep the original value for enums. I have around 180 values for a enum. I know its weird but thats how the code is. I would resort to bindings as a last resort if there is no other options. Thanks for your quick reply

Comment: @RajkumarPalani - Try using the binding file from this linked answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588287/jaxb-customize-field-naming-behaviorcamelcase-to-underscore-case/17590469#17590469